# Swift: Required initializer giving me an error message

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class named Alarm inheriting from NSObject, and in it, I have a property I'm having an issue with, alarmLastTriggeredDate:

```
class Alarm: NSObject {
    var alarmLastTriggeredDate: NSDate

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(alarmLastTriggeredDate, forKey: "alarmLastTriggeredDate")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let alarmLastTriggeredDateDecoded = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("alarmLastTriggeredDate") as? NSDate
        {
            alarmLastTriggeredDate = alarmLastTriggeredDateDecoded
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift, and not sure why I'm getting the following errors:

```
@override init: Property 'self.alarmLastTriggeredDate' not initialized at super.init call
@required init: Property 'self.alarmLastTriggeredDate' not initialized at implicitly generated super.init call
```

It seems the only way to fix this problem is to initialized it in both places, but that's redundant code, and seems wrong. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler must be sure that every non optional property is successfully [initialized](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

- before a call to a `super init` is performed
- **AND** before the object initialisation has been completed

That's why you need to populate `alarmLastTriggeredDate` inside bot initializers.

And no, it's not redundant code since someone could use one of the 2 initializers to create your `Alarm` object.